# arm-uclinux-gcc: crt1.o not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arm

I recently installed the arm-uclinux toolchain from arm-uclinux-tools-base-gcc3.4.0-20040610.sh . I ran the script and tried to compile a test program:

```
/usr/local/arm-uclinux-tools/bin/arm-uclinux-gcc hello.c -o hello

/usr/local/arm-uclinux-tools/lib/gcc/arm-uclinux/3.4.0/../../../../arm-uclinux/bin/ld.real: crt1.o: No such file: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I searched for hours about this issue and found nothing, except a hint about uclibc not being installed. Isn't it compiled along with the toolchain?

I'm using Ubuntu 11 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=960253). If you'd rather just skip to the point, here's a quote from it

> "Try using the command g++ instead of
>   gcc. The g++ command is used for
>   compiling C++ code (whereas gcc
>   defaults to C code), and will
>   automatically link against
>   libstdc++.so. If you really want to
>   use gcc to compile, you must manually
>   tell it to link against the c++
>   library, e.g. "

```
$ gcc foo.cpp -l stdc++
```

Comment: What does libstdc++ have to do with the main C runtime object not being found?

Comment: Nope, same problem with -l stdc++ :( I'm just compiling C anyway, so this shouldn't be a problem...